# Telerik Winform ButtonTextBox Element Button Parent

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, parent

I am trying a project with Telerik Winform in C#, and wish to get the parent control of `RightButtonItem` (`RadButtonElement`) from a `ButtonTextBox`, which is the `ButtonTextBox` itself.
Tried using `control.Parent` property, but the returned object is not the `ButtonTextBox` control.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], or at least what you have tried so far?  See: [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RightButtonItems collection contains different RadButtonElements. If you want to detect the parent control from one of the internal RadButtonElements, the easiest way to do it is to use the RadButtonElement.**ElementTree.Control** and cast it to RadButtonTextBox.

```
            Dictionary<int, string> glyphs = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        List<RadButtonElement> buttons = new List<RadButtonElement>();
        glyphs.Add(0, "");
        glyphs.Add(1, "");
        glyphs.Add(2, "");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9 - 1; i++)
        {
            RadButtonElement radButtonElement = new RadButtonElement();
            radButtonElement.DisplayStyle = Telerik.WinControls.DisplayStyle.Text;
            radButtonElement.TextElement.CustomFont = "TelerikWebUI";
            radButtonElement.TextElement.CustomFontSize = 10;
            radButtonElement.TextElement.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
            radButtonElement.Text = glyphs[i];
            buttons.Add(radButtonElement);
        }
        radButtonTextBox1.RightButtonItems.AddRange(buttons[0]);
        radButtonTextBox1.LeftButtonItems.AddRange(buttons[1], buttons[2]);
        radButtonTextBox1.AutoSize = false;
        radButtonTextBox1.Text = "";

        RadButtonTextBox btnTextBox = buttons[1].ElementTree.Control as RadButtonTextBox;
```